# Problems that are very difficult, but can be solved efficiently?

Tags: problem-solving

Are there any equations that look very hard to solve at first (e.g. many involved parameters etc), but can be solved/reduced efficiently solved with a certain algorithm?
I'd like to create some programming problems/puzzles - hence the question.

I had the following ideas:

Given some integer and an equation, find a solution. The idea is that the problem should quickly explode in a computationally large problem, but can be solved very efficiently with some algorithm/trick.

Can anyone suggest some problems that could fit here? Maybe some diophantine equation problem, or something similar?

Comment: The Rubiks cube comes to mind

Comment: Why do you ask? Some context would be helpful. $1 = xm + yn$  where the variables are integers  and $m$ and $n$ are given is a classical example.

Comment: Just trying to think of some interesting problems, that give you the wow-effect once you see the solution. @RobArthan I've recently seen a paper on the LLL algorithm, that is kinda falls into this category too.

Comment: @RobArthan I updated my question, to make it a bit more clear :)

Comment: Not sure how well this answers the question, but might be of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/q/244184/30186

Comment: This seems like a candidate for the discouraged tag "big-list". You'll have to clarify the scope, but my example would be the solution to Nim